# How to enable scrolling with the mouse wheel in Google Chrome?

Tags: mac, google-chrome, mouse, macos

I am currently running OSX 10.9.3 and Google Chrome Version 35.0.1916.114. When using Mozilla Firefox, I am able to scroll using the mouse wheel just fine. But with Google Chrome, it does not work. How am I able to enable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install a Google Chrome extension called [AutoScroll](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoscroll/occjjkgifpmdgodlplnacmkejpdionan). Make sure to refresh the pages you are currently on after the installation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

[SmoothScroll](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smoothscroll/nbokbjkabcmbfdlbddjidfmibcpneigj/related?hl=en) chrome extention, does exactly that.