# How to enable scrolling with the mouse wheel in Safari?

Tags: mac, safari, mouse, macos

I am currently running OSX 10.9.3 and Safari Version 7.0.4. When using Mozilla Firefox or Google Chrome, I am able to scroll using the mouse wheel just fine. But with Safari, it does not work. How am I able to enable this feature?

Comment: What kind of mouse do you have? Does it have some special configuration software? Scrolling with a mouse wheel should work fine anywhere.

Comment: @deceze I have a Logitec N50 mouse. It does not have any special configuration software, at least to my knowledge.

Comment: why did you post here that you can scroll in Chrome, but here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/133052/how-to-enable-scrolling-with-the-mouse-wheel-in-google-chrome that you can't?

Comment: @dwightk Because that issue has been resolved. How is that relevant to this question?

Comment: It was just weird.